# While requesting access token reddit api is returning 429 error

Tags: java, reddit

When am trying to retrieve the access token getting 429 :Too Many Requests error,i have followed the steps mentioned in the link --> https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2

what could be the reason for the error .here is my code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{ 
    String url3 ="https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token?";

    OAuthRequest get_info_request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url3);
    get_info_request.setCharset("UTF-8");
    get_info_request.addBodyParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    get_info_request.addBodyParameter("redirect_uri", "xxxxxxxxxx");
    get_info_request.addBodyParameter("code", "xxxxxxxxx");
    get_info_request.addBodyParameter("USER_AGENT", "desktop:net.dean.ayati:v0.9.0 (by /u/ayati)");
    System.out.println(get_info_request.getCompleteUrl()+get_info_request.getBodyContents());
    Response json_response = get_info_request.send();
    System.out.println(json_response.getBody());
    JSONObject jsonResp = new JSONObject(json_response.getBody());
    System.out.println("is" + jsonResp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While HTTP headers are case-insensitive you still have **USER_AGENT** spelt incorrectly.

It uses a '-' not '_' in it.

Try:

```
get_info_request.addBodyParameter("User-Agent", "desktop:net.dean.ayati:v0.9.0 (by /u/ayati)");
```

and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried it still am getting the same error.Any other suggestions?

Comment: are you getting any X_Ratelimit_* headers in your response indicating that you are over limit?

Comment: no every time i am  getting this type of response : {"message": "Too Many Requests", "error": 429}.